# How to import crypto from OpenSSL (pyOpenSSL) correctly in command-line?

Tags: cryptography, pyopenssl

Environment: Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS x64, OpenSSL v1.0.2h, pyOpenSSL v16.1.0, Python v2.7.3, Eclipse Oxygen.1a (4.7.1a).

Program named 'test.py':

```
#/usr/bin/env python
#encoding:utf-8

from OpenSSL import crypto
print crypto.__file__

print "hello world"
```

This program is run in Eclipse and the following result is obtained.

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/crypto.pyc
hello world
```

Nevertheless, when the same program is run in command-line, error occurs and the information is given as follows.

```
$ python test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 4, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import crypto
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import rand, crypto, SSL
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/rand.py", line 12, in <module>
    from OpenSSL._util import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/_util.py", line 6, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.bindings.openssl.binding import Binding
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/binding.py", line 14, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.bindings._openssl import ffi, lib
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_cffi_backend.so: undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS2_FromUnicode
```

The program in Eclipse and command-line imports the same 'crypto.pyc', why does it work in Eclipse while fail in command-line (UCS2)? How to import crypto from OpenSSL correctly in command-line? Thank you in advance!